# What format is the output from a GA aircraft microphone? WAV? MP3? or some other format

Tags: avionics, radio

I'm trying to develop a personal weather station observation to a voice output on Unicom when pilot activated.

To start, I need to know what format is in the output from a GA aircraft microphone?  WAV? MP3? or some other format.

Comment: Why do you need a microphone to transmit telemetry data from the ground? You should use your data to control a [text-to-speech generator](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10000018738091.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra) and modulate the transmitter. Note using Unicom for such application likely requires an authorization.

Comment: I want to broadcast weather data over Unicom through a handheld aircraft radio on pilot controlled input.  This is currently being done commercially but you have to buy the complete system, sensors and all at a very significant price.  The TTS portion has several solutions available with several output forms, i.e. WAV, MP3, etc.

Comment: I see, this is possible of course. You have to use the raw analog audio frequency output which might be labeled HP or SP if there is an integrated audio amplifier. Codec outputs like wav or mp3 are not made for this. However you need to convert the impedance of the analog output (possibly 8 $\small \Omega$) in order to meet the one of a mike input (more about 200 $\small \Omega$ to 10k $\small \Omega$), else you'll experience a huge distortion or a tiny voice. You may want to ask how to do on the [radioamateur Q/A site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions), this is one of their topics.

Comment: So the sensor data is sent to Google Docs, then run through TTS then to the transmitter.  When the pilot calls Unicom, the current weather observation is transmitted back to the pilot.

Comment: I cannot comment further without elements (e.g. do you use a MCU), and anyway this is not the place, still the principle is to convert sensors data to text (whether you need a txt file or can use a live ascii/unicode serial stream depends on your TTS board), feed TTS with text, convert TTS audio output to the correct impedance and send the corrected audio to the mike input of the transceiver. How the transmission process is triggered by the pilot is another part (ham repeaters have remote control by tone to kill uplink squelch, this is not different). This looks like an interesting project.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  There are already automated WX broadcasts available, how is what you are attempting different?

Comment: I'm trying to get a specific station data out to the pilots going to that specific airport.  Interestingly, there is already an automated station 5 miles away but the winds are consistently different between the two stations.  That system costs 250k with 10k per year maintenance/calibration, much beyond out financial capability.

Comment: Google 'private awos' to get links to systems that do this. Budget ones are less than $10k.

Answer (score 17):

Analog............................

Answer (score 5):

*Sound* is ultimately analog. The waves of compressed and rarefied air molecules represent an analog signal. A microphone converts differences in air pressure into an analog electrical signal; a speaker converts an analog electrical signal into differences in air pressure.

How that electrical signal is processed between the microphone and the speaker is a design choice; you can use an ADC to convert the signal into a digital format for processing and storage before using a DAC to convert it back into an analog signal for transmittal. Or you can process and store the analog signal without ever converting it to digital.

If you do use a digital format, you must consider tradeoffs, such as: which format uses more or less storage space, which format is easier for your software stack to process, whether a format stores enough information to avoid introducing artifacts in the signal, etc. But as long as you convert the digital format to an analog signal, your transmitter equipment will not care about the format you used.

Answer (score 4):

The output of a GA microphone is an analog signal consisting of a very rapidly varying AC voltage, in the range of ~tens of millivolts to hundreds of millivolts depending on the type of microphone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it would be a digital microphone, the output is likely to be raw [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) (pulse code modulation), or sometimes MP3 or AAC. But the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aviation_headset_connectors#:%7E:text=The%20following%20electrical%20connectors%20are%20commonly%20used%20in,5%20Neutrik%20neutriCON%208-pin%20connector%20%5B11%5D%20%5B12%5D%20%5B13%5D) of common headset connectors as used in aviation appears listing connectors for the analog signal.